# API is working in POSTMAN but post method is not during send mail in ANGULAR

Tags: angular, typescript, api, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing AspNETCoreAPI/Angular project. I am trying to send mail and its working in backend. But in frontend, it is not. I can get the datas and controlled in console.

> [Here is the postman 'OKAY' result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nUW5.png)

> [Here is the debug result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD3kl.png)

**MailRequest service.cs**

```cs
public async Task SendEmailAsync(MailRequest mailRequest)
        {
            var email = new MimeMessage();
            email.Sender = MailboxAddress.Parse(_mailSettings.Mail);
            email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(mailRequest.ToEmail));
            email.Subject = mailRequest.Subject;
            var builder = new BodyBuilder();
            if (mailRequest.Attachments != null)
            {
                byte[] fileBytes;
               foreach (var file in mailRequest.Attachments)
                {
                    if (file.Length > 0)
                    {
                        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            file.CopyTo(ms);
                            fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                        }
                        builder.Attachments.Add(file.FileName, fileBytes, ContentType.Parse(file.ContentType));
                    }
                }
            }
            builder.HtmlBody = mailRequest.Body;
            email.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
            using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Connect(_mailSettings.Host, _mailSettings.Port, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
            smtp.Authenticate(_mailSettings.Mail, _mailSettings.Password);
            await smtp.SendAsync(email);
            smtp.Disconnect(true);
        }
```

**mail.service.ts**

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { observable, Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MailService {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) { }

  contactForm = this.fb.group({
    ToEmail:[''],
    Attachments: null,
    Subject:[''],
    Body:['']
  });
  sendEmail(){
    var request = { 
      ToEmail: this.contactForm.value.ToEmail,
      Attachments: this.contactForm.value.Attachments,
      Subject: this.contactForm.value.Subject,
      Body: this.contactForm.value.Body, };
     var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:5000/api/mail/send',JSON.stringify(request),{headers: headers});
  }
```

**mail.component.ts**

```js
export class SendmailComponent implements OnInit {


  public submitted: boolean;


  constructor(public mailservice:MailService) { }



  onSubmit(){
    this.mailservice.sendEmail().subscribe((res:any) => {
      console.log("ok");
    },
    err => {
      if (err.status === 500)
        console.log("error");
    }
    );
    // console.log(value, valid);
  }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.mailservice.contactForm.reset();
  }
 
}
```

**mail.component.html**

```html
<nb-card>
    <nb-card-body class="bodyy">
        <form [formGroup]="mailservice.contactForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input  type="text" formControlName="ToEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
              <div [hidden]= "mailservice.contactForm.controls.ToEmail.valid || mailservice.contactForm.controls.ToEmail.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
                <span *ngIf="!mailservice.contactForm.controls.ToEmail.valid"> Email is required!</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Subject</label>
              <input  type="text" formControlName="Subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter subject">
              <div [hidden]= "mailservice.contactForm.controls.Subject.valid || mailservice.contactForm.controls.Subject.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
                <span *ngIf="!mailservice.contactForm.controls.Subject.valid"> Subject is required!</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Message</label>
              <textarea rows="3" type="text" formControlName="Body" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
              <div [hidden]= "mailservice.contactForm.controls.Body.valid || mailservice.contactForm.controls.Body.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
                <span *ngIf="!mailservice.contactForm.controls.Body.valid"> Message is required!</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Attachments</label>
                <input type="file" formControlName="Attachments" placeholder="Add something"/>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [class.btn-pulse]="submitted">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

it seems that your body is sent as a json object while your API is expecting a formdata object (see [MDN using form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)
try building your body as suggested in the link above, it should be ok then!

Comment: Thank you very much :) I solved the problem !